# the 'if' condition check is not working for me when I use awk

Tags: awk

Have a set of users having disk space in /nobackup. I want to filter users who are using more the 70G of space

INPUT format: 
Disk space dir/username

INPUT:

```
351G    /nobackup/dwoo
80G     /nobackup/snjos
73G     /nobackup/ka
67G     /nobackup/mseer
67G     /nobackup/monche
65G     /nobackup/sambut
64G     /nobackup/submee
64G     /nobackup/jushe
64G     /nobackup/dichr
63G     /nobackup/n
```

Modifying this output using AWK to only print the names if disk space is above 70G

```
cat /tmp/test | awk '{var=substr($1, 1, length($1)-1); split($2,a,"/"); if(var > 70) {print a[3]}}'
```

In output I only get

```
snjos
ka
```

Where I should get

```
dwoo
snjos
ka
```

Comment: You are experiencing alphabetic comparison, that's why '351' is less than '70'. You want to do a numeric comparison. You might try using the strtonum() function to convert your string field values to a number. e.g. ` if(strtonum($1) > 70)`

Comment: Does your first column always end in G or could that size be in K, M,  etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $1 is a *string* (it contains non-digits), the `>` operator is a *lexical* comparison (i.e. dictionary order) where "3" < "7". You need to convert $1 to a number first: put it in a numeric context by adding zero.

```
if ($1 + 0 > 70) {print a[3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `var` but never using it.  I would recommend letting awk strip the G and split the path by changing the field separator:

```
 awk '$1 > 70 { print $NF}' FS=[G/] /tmp/test
```

Note that this approach will incorrectly match a user using 800M, but that's an inherent flaw of you approach which needs a different solution.

Comment: Sry about the $1, dont know when I added that, but even with using var, I was getting the same answer. But thx for pointing out the flaw. The below command works on that. "cat /tmp/test | awk '$1 ~ /.*G/ {gsub(/[G]+\n\t$/,"",$1); split($2,a,"/"); if($1 + 0 > 70) {print a[3]}}'"\